# How could my build passed, while it should not?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gitlab, yaml

So I am learning about CI and pipelines and all that stuff and I just added my yaml file to my repository and it built successfully and tested successfully, but when I made a change in the code (I removed a semicolumn) it still said that the build was successful while it should say it had a error. I have no idea if my yaml file is not good, or what it is.

I am suspecting my yaml file is not as it should be but I did another post about it and I got no reaction.

**My Yaml file:**

[image: my yaml file]

**My changed code:**

[image: my changed code]

Obviously, the code should error since there is no semicolumn anymore.

I build this project with gradle also and the yaml file there is:

```
build:
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
 
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
 
after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

This code works like it should(on the other project) so I searched the maven version of that code, but could not find it.
Can anyone help me to confirm that the problem is in the yaml file and help me to what the yaml file should be (if that's the problem)?
Thanks!

Comment: Check from which branch code is pulled by CI pipe line. If you are code merge is pending with master or dev branch it will still pull your old code.

Answer (score 1):

Is the pipeline posted above your complete pipeline for your maven build? Your pipeline does nothing except echoing outputs.

If you need to build with maven you would need something like this:

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test

build_a:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install -DskipTests --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version

build_b:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version
```

Comment: I get the following error trying this: mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You need to use an image that has maven installed like image: maven:latest
I updated my answer to include the image